# Setting expire cookie for popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I would like to set an expire cookie for my popup window. I've inserted my HTML into this post and have also included my CodePen as well, if that helps.

The cookie should expire after 3 months maximum, unless of course the user deletes their cookies.

I'm not looking to use jQuery, I'm looking for a pure JavaScript or CSS solution.

If the cookie exists, I do not want to run the code for my popup. If it does not exist, I want to run the code for my popup and then set the cookie.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVXQaE

Thank you.

```css
/* style link popup */
a.popup-link {
padding:17px 0;
text-align: center;
margin:10% auto;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #FFBA00;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 0px 0px #eea900;
display: block;
}
a.popup-link:hover {
background-color: #ff9900;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0px #eea900;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
}
/* end link popup*/
/* animasi popup */@-webkit-keyframes autopopup {
from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes autopopup {
from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes autopopup {
from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}
/* end animasi popup */
/*style popup */
#popup {
z-index:9999;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:0;
-webkit-animation:autopopup 2s;
-moz-animation:autopopup 2s;
animation:autopopup 2s;
}
#popup:target {
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}@media (min-width: 768px){
.popup-container {
width:600px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
.popup-container {
width:100%;
}
}
.popup-container {
position: relative;
margin:7% auto;
padding:30px 50px;
background-color: #fafafa;
color:#333;
border-radius: 3px;
}a.popup-close {
position: absolute;
top:3px;
right:3px;
background-color: #333;
padding:7px 10px;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 1;
color:#fff;
}
/* end style popup *//* style isi popup */
.popup-form {
margin:10px auto;
}
.popup-form h2 {
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 37px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.popup-form .input-group {
margin:10px auto;
}
.popup-form .input-group input {
padding:17px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius:3px;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
.popup-form .input-group input:focus {
outline-color:#FB8833;
}
.popup-form .input-group input[type="email"] {
border:0px;
position: relative;
}
.popup-form .input-group input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #FB8833;
color: #fff;
border: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
.popup-form .input-group input[type="submit"]:focus {
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px 3px #ea7722;
}
/* end style isi popup */
```

```html
<div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup">
<div class="popup-container"><!-- Popup Contents, just modify with your own -->
<h2><strong>SIGN UP FOR OUR EMAILS BELOW AND RECEIVE:</strong></h2>
<p><strong>10% OFF OF YOUR NEXT ORDER</strong><br/>
<div class="input-group">
</div>
<!-- Popup contents is until here--><a class="popup-close" href="#popup">X</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: all you need to know : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp you will find the *create a cookie with javascript* section particularly interesting

Comment: @litelite All righty, the next question becomes, how can I use this to run and not run certain code? If the cookie exists, I don't want to run the above code in my post. If it doesn't exist, then run the above code and then set cookie.

Comment: you will need more JS for that. you could try to only add the html only if the cookie is present (see the *A Function to Get a Cookie* section in the link i commented earlier)